# Does Windows 7 only index the first x characters of a file and can I change x?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I recently ran into an issue where a legacy SQL script which is required to be run to enable support for a component of our application was overwriting a more recent version of a particular stored procedure.  The solution as far as our process is concerned is to remove the update to the stored procedure from the legacy script since it is managed within the standard schema (ie. it shouldn't have been in the legacy script in the first place).

To remove the SP I searched the script folder for the stored procedure name and then opened the scripts it found.  I found the SP on line 32508 of the file and removed it then searched the script folder again to get no results.

A few hours of frustrating hair pulling later I opened the file again and did a manual search for the SP only to find a second copy of it on line 97031.  This string was not detected by Windows Explorer search even though the first instance was.  The folder in question is indexed, and the search was working just fine for at least the first 32508 lines of the file.

So to my questions: is there a limit to the number of characters per file that Windows 7 will index?  Can I change this limit?

Comment: Instead of struggling with Windows Search and trying to overcome its irritating limitations, why not simply use a better text search/[grep utility](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net)? Even find/findstr from the command line might be better TBH.

Comment: @Karan is there one that will integrate with the search box at the top of Windows Explorer?

Comment: I don't know of any such program; never had a need to look beyond the programs I already mentioned in my previous comment (along with my text editor and IDE's Find in Files feature).